# How to Validate Input value at two decimal point by inputting from number pad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom-events

I have a JavaScript function to Validate only decimal value.I use the JavaScript `onkeyup` event.

```js
function onlyNumeric(evt) {
  var theEvent = evt || window.event;
  var key = theEvent.keyCode || theEvent.which;
  var exclusions = [8, 46];

  if (exclusions.indexOf(key) > -1) {
    return;
  }

  key = String.fromCharCode(key);

  var regex = /[0-9]|\./;

  if (!regex.test(key)) {
    theEvent.returnValue = false;

    if (theEvent.preventDefault) {
      theEvent.preventDefault();
    }

    return false;
  }

  return true;
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="onlyNumeric(event)" class="form-control" id="ColumnName" name="ColumnName">
```

It's working fine when I put value not from the number pad. But when I put value by number pad it's not working. So how can i fixed it?

Also I need fix it at two decimal point. But how can I do it?

Is `onkeyup` event Ok for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use this Regex pattern :

```
/^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/
```

Explanation :

```
\d    match a digit...   
+     one or more times    
(     begin group...     
?:    but do not capture anything     
\.    match literal dot     
\d    match a digit...     
{1,2} one or two times    
)     end group   
?     make the entire group optional
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="onlyNumeric(event)" class="form-control" id="ColumnName" name="ColumnName">

<script>
function onlyNumeric(evt) {
    var rx = /^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    var ele = document.getElementById("ColumnName");
    if(rx.test(ele.value)) { 
       console.log("true");
    }else{ 
       console.log("false");
    }
}
</script>
```

Another solution using [addEventListener()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener) instead of onkeyup:

```html
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="ColumnName" name="ColumnName">

<script>
function onlyNumeric(evt) {
    var rx = /^\d+(?:\.\d{1,2})?$/;
    var ele = document.getElementById("ColumnName");
    if(rx.test(ele.value)) { 
       console.log("true");
    }else{ 
       console.log("false");
    }
}

var el = document.getElementById("ColumnName");
el.addEventListener("input", onlyNumeric, false);

</script>
```

Comment: Is it perfect for using onkeyup event for this purpose?

Comment: i think _onkeyup_ could be getting clobbered by another script, then you can use another solution by _addEventListener_, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 4):

Below is the code to help you out:

```js
function onlyNumeric(evt) {
    var pattern = /^\d{0,4}(\.\d{0,2})?$/i;
    var element = document.getElementById("ColumnName");
    if(pattern.test(element.value)) {
      console.log("Vadid number:" + element.value);
    } else {
      console.log("Invadid number:" + element.value);
    }
}
```

```html
<input type="text" onkeyup="onlyNumeric(event)" class="form-control" id="ColumnName" name="ColumnName">
```

Comment: Is onkeyup event Ok for this purpose?

Comment: Yes, its perfectly fine. With onkeyup, you can have realtime validations and errors messages.

Answer (score 0):

Use this jquery plugin it validate decimal behaviour while typing and mouse click
https://github.com/sarkfoundation/Decimal-Behavior

```html
   <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type='text/javascript' src="https://rawgit.com/sarkfoundation/Decimal-Behavior/master/sark-decimal/sark-decimal.js"></script>
    <input type="text" data-behaviour="decimal">
```